# edit_user_profile and show_user_profile are not firing inside a class

Tags: plugins, hooks, users, actions

I have a clean installation of Wordpress, without any extra plugins installed (only for testing purpose).

I have created a test-plugin and declared the following class:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );
class Test_Plugin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('show_user_profile', array($this,'add_user_profile_inputs'));
        add_action('edit_user_profile', array($this,'add_user_profile_inputs'));
    }

    public function add_user_profile_inputs( $user )
    {
?>
        <h3>New input fields area</h3>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

The problem with this code is that the hooks will not fire. When I navigate to the Edit User or Your Profile pages, there is nothing changed.

If I write the code outside the class, the hooks will fire and the Edit User and Your Profile pages are changed with the addition of the new  text:

```
<?php    
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );
    add_action('show_user_profile', 'add_user_profile_inputs');
    add_action('edit_user_profile', 'add_user_profile_inputs');

    function add_user_profile_inputs( $user )
    {
        ?>
        <h3>New input fields area</h3>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

I don't understand why, if someone can please explain this.
I would like to keep everything inside the Class. Is this possible? and how?
Does this behavior apply to other hooks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where are you calling the class? A class by itself will do nothing unless it's used.

So, add at the very end `$activate = new Test_Plugin();`

Comment: Indeed. Rookie mistake!